# Increase or Decrease an Integer Within a NSString

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring, nsinteger

My app is a simple blog app.  I parse an XML, and build custom HTML code from the parsed parts, and load that HTML into a webview.  Not everyone has the same quality of vision, so I am trying to add simple buttonsto add or decrease the font size.  Currently, the HTML may look like:

> font size=5 The Title.../font         font size = 3 The body of text.../font

What I would like to do is take whatever number is listed, and increase or decrease by 1.

Any suggestions on how I can take just those 2 numbers (don't want to increase other numbers that may be in body of article) and increase or decrease incrementally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend stuffing the HTML you parsed out of the XML into a "`NSMutableString`" object and then hunt through the mutable string object looking for the ranges of all substrings that match the pattern "`font size=`".

Once you find those ranges, you should be able to get the font sizes and then put them into a "`NSInteger`" via something like `[NSString integerValue]` which you can then increment and put back into the mutable string object.  Obviously there's some extra detail I'm not thinking too hard about, like how to replace a "`9`" in the mutable string with a "`10`" or to tell the difference between a font size of "`10`" and one that's "`100`".  But at least this should be a good start for you.

Comment: I honestly have no idea where to even begin with that.  I just want to take the number after font size= and add or subtract to it.